# Responsive - Font size doesn't load

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, width, font-size

I builded a responsive website from phone to big screen. 
When I make my screen bigger my font size is getting bigger too.
But when I navigate or open in big screen the font size starts with the 100% as my mobile version. When I change the size again it will load the right font size.

Each 200 added  pixel width makes the font size 10% bigger but not if I navigate or I have to resize it so it loads...

Anyone that can help?

Comment: Please show some code to illustrate your errors / problems.

Comment: html {
    font-size:100%;
}
@media (min-width:600px) {
 html {
    font-size:110%;
 }


It worked in mozilla and not in chrome, when I load my page on big screen on chrome it will take the font-size of the mobile version (the first one), when I resize it take the right one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bunch of known issues in Chrome when a font-size is set on HTML tag:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=320754

I use this to be on the safe side (you don't have to use rems, of course):

```
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
body, input, select, textarea, table, td {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

Comment: thanks man... I tried so many things, all I had to do was switching the html into body on my bigger screens :)

Comment: The standard thank you on StackOverflow is accepting and/or up voting answers :)